# Как можно уменьшить количество строк в программе?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Как можно уменьшить количество строк в программе:

```
name = str(input("Введите ваше имя: "))
x = len(name)
while x > 100:
   print('Введённое вами имя превышает максимальное количество символов. Пожалуйста попробуйте ещё раз.')
   name = str(input("Please, print your name: "))
   x = len(name)
else:
   print("Здравствуйте,", name + '!')
```

Comment: Имейте в виду, это не тикток, здесь не приветствуются такие никнеймы. Если у вас аккаунт на один раз, лучше сразу удалите.

Comment: str не надо. Из input() уже приходит строка.

Comment: А зачем? Не надо стремиться писать меньше строк, надо стремиться писать ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо цикла с постусловием в python используется бесконечный цикл с ручным выходом:

```
while True:
  name = input("Введите ваше имя: ")
  if len(name) <= 100:
    break
  print('Введённое вами имя превышает максимальное количество символов(100). Пожалуйста попробуйте ещё раз.')

print("Здравствуйте,", name + '!')
```

Comment: ``if len(name) <= 100: `` ещё минус строчка

Comment: Ну, ок, уговорили))

Comment: Удаляйте комментарии, когда вопрос исчерпан. А то они без контекста типа "не о чём".